# Rendre accessible la 4e dose de vaccin aux gens (les) plus vulnérables

Tags: expressions, articles, locutions-comparatives

*La 4e dose de vaccin maintenant disponible pour certains* dans *24 heures* :

> Même si la plupart des mesures sanitaires sont levées, la COVID-19 n'est pas derrière nous. Le Québec a enregistré plus de 2000 cas mardi, et la Santé publique
> vient de rendre accessible la 4e dose de vaccin **aux gens plus
> vulnérables**.

Le tour *aux gens plus vulnérables* me gêne, j'ai l'impression qu'il manque quelque chose. J'aurais écrit *aux gens les plus vulnérables* ou *aux gens qui sont plus vulnérables que la majorité de la population*.

D'autant plus qu'il est écrit plus bas :

> Les autorités sanitaires du Québec ont recommandé mercredi une
> quatrième dose de vaccin contre la COVID-19 aux octogénaires et **aux
> personnes les plus vulnérables**.

Est-ce que *aux gens plus vulnérables* est correct dans la première phrase ?

Answer (score 2):

Je ne vois pas ce qui justifie le manque d'article ; il faudrait que dans le contexte on reconnaisse l'existence d'une norme de vulnérabilité au-delà de laquelle on est forcé de constater que l'on est en présence d'un cas critique qui demande des mesures spéciales, en l'occurrence une quatrième dose. En l'absence de ce contexte, l'article s'impose, dans un contexte qui est celui du superlatif absolu.

Comment: Je ne trouve pas cet article en ligne, mais, à mon avis, le contexte que vous décrivez n'y est pas présent. C'est la deuxème phrase de l'article, j'ajouterai la 1ère à la question.

Comment: France: La vaccination contre le Covid-19 élargie aux personnes plus vulnérables; aussi: sans personnes. Je ne trouve pas gens dans des articles formels en France. https://actu.orange.fr/societe/videos/la-vaccination-contre-le-covid-19-elargie-aux-personnes-plus-vulnerables-CNT000001wpL81.html

Answer (score 2):

Une recherche sur Internet de l'expression "*aux gens plus vulnérables*" retourne une cinquantaine de pages, toutes québécoises, dont une dizaine d'articles de presse.

On peut donc en déduire:

- Que l'expression est rare mais correcte dans le sens où elle correspond à un usage clairement établi.
- Qu'il s'agit d'un québécisme équivalent à *aux personnes les plus vulnérables*, beaucoup plus courant dans toute la francophonie.

Answer (score 2):

Sauf exceptions ou par archaïsme (« Il choisissait [...] pour sa promenade sans but les ruelles plus
étroites et plus noires », Bernanos), le superlatif relatif prend normalement l'article défini après le 17e s. (LBU14, § 987 et ss.). Sur un site comme *Lapresse*, avec le nom *personnes* et l'adjectif *vulnérables*, sans analyser les résultats on trouve [un emploi](https://www.lapresse.ca/recherche?q=%22personnes%20plus%20vuln%C3%A9rables%22#gsc.tab=0&gsc.q=%22personnes%20plus%20vuln%C3%A9rables%22&gsc.page=1) de *plus* sans l'article pour cinq emplois [avec](https://www.lapresse.ca/recherche?q=%22personnes%20les%20plus%20vuln%C3%A9rables%22#gsc.tab=0&gsc.q=%22personnes%20les%20plus%20vuln%C3%A9rables%22&gsc.page=1) ; de prime abord ce serait minoritaire ou moins fréquent comme usage. On n'a pas la source du quotidien, mais on a le [communiqué](https://www.quebec.ca/nouvelles/actualites/details/pandemie-de-la-covid-19-administration-dune-dose-de-rappel-4e-dose-de-vaccin-dans-les-milieux-de-vie-et-chez-les-personnes-de-80-ans-et-plus-ou-immunodeprimees-38853) à l'origine de l'information, qui est différent :

> Cette nouvelle dose de vaccin vise à nous assurer de mieux protéger
> les personnes *les plus vulnérables* contre les conséquences d'une
> augmentation de la contagion au Québec. [...] (Le ministre de la
> santé, je souligne)

On trouve cependant des références aux « personnes fragilisées », et on parle de prudence « au contact de personnes immunodéprimées ou vulnérables ». C'est possiblement une tournure plus [régionale](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/49984) comme on l'a dit ailleurs mais peut-être qu'on perçoit parfois aussi un peu ce superlatif comme un comparatif implicite avec une personne d'âge moyen en santé plutôt qu'une détermination plus péremptoire (une personne âgée ou immunodéprimée n'est pas nécessairement ni fondamentalement la plus vulnérable de la société du seul fait de cette caractéristique). Peut-être qu'il y a un désir d'atténuation de l'étiquette associée à la qualification et qu'on pense davantage à une forme de clientèle. Les auteurs sont clairement « ceux qui nous peuvent mieux esclaircir de cet Usage » (Vaugelas !).

Answer (score 2):

Pour moi, la différence entre les deux est que la version avec article est un superlatif et celle sans article est un comparatif. Dans ce dernier cas, il me manque une référence de comparaison.

Avec **les plus vulnérables** j'entends un ordre de priorité que je n'entends pas avec  **plus vulnérables**.